# How to unmarshal a JSON field which is either an struct or array of stuct?

Tags: arrays, json, go, unmarshalling

#### Use case

I have an API in which I receive the user input as an object or array of objects. Like this:

##### JSON without Array

```json
{
  "sign": {
    "page_no": 1,
    "x_coord": 100,
    "y_coord": 300
  }
}
```

##### JSON with Array

```json
{
  "sign": [
    {
      "page_no": 1,
      "x_coord": 100,
      "y_coord": 300
    },
    {
      "page_no": 2,
      "x_coord": 200,
      "y_coord": 400
    }
  ]
}
```

##### Struct to Unmarshal to

```golang
type Document struct {
  Sign []Sign `json:"sign"` // or just Sign
}

type Sign struct {
  PageNo int `json:"page_no"`
  XCoord int `json:"x_coord"`
  YCoord int `json:"y_coord"`
}
```

I cannot make the `Sign` field on the `Document` as an array for all user inputs due to legacy reasons so It needs to be both array of `Sign` as well as just `Sign`.

How to unmarshal it so that it can handle both of the JSON requests below?

#### I Know That...

We can use `map[string]interface{}` instead of the struct but that will lead to too many key assertions which you don't have to do when I am using struct because I can leverage the zero values for them.

Also, [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26835815/6546827) seems okay but I wanted to know is a there better way to do it?

Comment: Are you fine with introducing relying or errors, and decoding twice if the JSON is of `Sign` type?

Comment: The linked answer is how to do it (implement `UnmarshalJSON()` for `*Sign`). The legacy design is bad and this is the consequence.

Comment: Related video here: https://youtu.be/vsN11YAEJHY?t=604

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without `interface{}` (or type assertions) at all, by implementing a custom unmarshaler. I would implement the unmarshaler by peeking inside the JSON, and checking to see if it starts with a square bracket or curly brace... skipping whitespace.

See the [json.Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface in the docs.

```golang
type Document struct {
    Sign SignList
}

type SignList []Sign

func (l *SignList) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    for _, b := range d {
        switch b {
        // These are the only valid whitespace in a JSON object.
        case ' ', '\n', '\r', '\t':
        case '[':
            return json.Unmarshal(d, (*[]Sign)(l))
        case '{':
            var obj Sign
            if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &obj); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            *l = []Sign{obj}
            return nil
        default:
            return errors.New("sign must be object or list")
        }
    }
    return errors.New("sign must be object or list")
}
```

This may seem a little bit clumsy. Oh well. There are alternative JSON unmarshaling libraries for Go besides encoding/json. Try out an alternative JSON library if you like. This code works with just encoding/json.

Here is how you can test that this code works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
)

type Sign struct {
    X int
}

func main() {
    cases := []string {
        `{"Sign": {"X": 1}}`,
        `{"Sign": [{"X": 1}, {"X": 2}]}`,
    }
    for _, c := range cases {
        var doc Document
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(c), &doc); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("Document: %+v\n", &doc)
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Document: &{Sign:[{X:1}]}
Document: &{Sign:[{X:1} {X:2}]}
```

Comment: With other libraries you recommend which can abstract away this clumsiness?

Comment: @Dietrich I seem to be missing something VERY obvious here, but I understand you're peeking into the JSON here. Where are you ensuring you only check the type of the `sign` key, so that addition of new top-level properties in the future doesn't break this?

Comment: @AyushGupta: That is unnecessary. Refer to the documentation if you wish to understand how the `json.Unmarshaler` interface works. https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler

Comment: @Aziz: I don't have any specific libraries to recommend. You would want to read the documentation for those libraries, if you decide that you are not happy using encoding/json.

Answer (score 1):

Create a slice type with a custom json unmarshaler method. Then in that unmarshaler, you can detect which type of input you have, and behave accordingly. This approach is detailed further in my video [Advanced JSON handling in Go](https://youtu.be/vsN11YAEJHY?t=604).

```golang
type Signs []Sign

func (s *Signs) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    if d[0] == '{' {
        // We know it's a single object
        var v Sign
        err := json.Unmarshal(d, &v)
        *s = Signs{v}
        return err
    }
    // Otherwise it's an array
    var v []Sign
    err := json.Unmarshal(d, &v)
    *s = Signs(v)
    return err
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Implement a type to test which can validate your data is of, and use that to as a check.

For example:

```golang
package main

type SignTest struct {
    Sign map[string]interface{} `json:"sign"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{
  "sign": [
    {
      "page_no": 1,
      "x_coord": 100,
      "y_coord": 300
    },
    {
      "page_no": 2,
      "x_coord": 200,
      "y_coord": 400
    }
  ]
}`

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &SignTest{})

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Document Type")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Sign Type")
    }
}
```

Prints `Document Type`, while

```golang
package main


type SignTest struct {
    Sign map[string]interface{} `json:"sign"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{
  "sign": {
    "page_no": 1,
    "x_coord": 100,
    "y_coord": 300
  }
}`

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &SignTest{})

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Document Type")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Sign Type")
    }
}
```

Prints `Sign Type`.

But here might be an error while unmarshalling the object other than the sign is an array or not., If you want even more safety, check the error message of the error that is should be as expected before assuming it as `Document`.

Comment: There might be an error while unmarshalling the object other than the sign is an array or not.

Comment: @Aziz Yep that's why I said `If you want even more safety, check the error message of the error before parsing it as Document`

Comment: You just need to check if the error message is as expected when it should be a Document, right now is: `json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field SignTest.sign of type map[string]interface {}` as per the current code